# Sass not working in Svelte and StorybookJS

Tags: sass, material-design, svelte, storybook

I am using `Google Material` on `Svelte` and thank GOD finally was able to successfully make it work. Now, I created it in a separate code base. On the other hand I am actually creating a separate codebase for different components in `StorybookJS`. So when I ported my working codebase (actually copy pasted the component) the button for example that I am testing is not working anymore. I checked all the necessary npm installations that I need and it's all good.

But now when I check the `Developer Tools` on my browser (I am using `Brave`) I got this error:

`Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:60809/theme-mui.scss' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

My **theme-mui.scss** mentioned on the error above is the initializer for my `Google Material` to work on `Svelte` (or other framework for that matter). I tried to transfer the above `scss` file to no avail. I followed the instruction of setup from my separate code base but it still is not working. I tried to follow the sass config using this [link](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/) from `Storybook` but still to no avail.  What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Do you use Webpack for the App or Rollup?

Comment: That's a good question. I think because of `Svelte`, i'm using rollup.

Comment: In order for sass to work, you need a plugin in rollup. Many people seem to use ```svelte-preprocess```. When you use this plugin, you can pass it a ```scss``` option to use sass. You can find more about it here: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess

Comment: I did have a `svelte-preprocess` already installed but still the same.